# Sort a dynamically allocated array with a quicksort algorithm in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, dynamic

I am trying to write a quick sort algorithm titled `sort_int_vector` that can work on integer data in a dynamically allocated array to sort it in the `FORWARD` or `REVERSE` direction.  In this example, the dynamically allocated vector contains the values of `[ 2, 5, 3, 1, 4 ]` and sorts them in the forward direction.  As expected the function returns the array as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`.  However, when I run valgrind on the implementation it returns the following error that appears to indicate that I may have overlapping memory.

```
==38913== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==38913== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==38913== Using Valgrind-3.19.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==38913== Command: ./test
==38913== 
==38913== Invalid read of size 4
==38913==    at 0x1092F1: partition_int_vec (main.c:97)
==38913==    by 0x10937B: sort_int_vec (main.c:124)
==38913==    by 0x10939F: sort_int_vec (main.c:126)
==38913==    by 0x10939F: sort_int_vec (main.c:126)
==38913==    by 0x109423: main (main.c:134)
==38913==  Address 0x4a65054 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==38913==    at 0x4841888: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==38913==    by 0x1091C1: init_int_vector (main.c:38)
==38913==    by 0x1093CD: main (main.c:131)
==38913== 
==38913== Invalid read of size 4
==38913==    at 0x109319: partition_int_vec (main.c:101)
==38913==    by 0x10937B: sort_int_vec (main.c:124)
==38913==    by 0x10939F: sort_int_vec (main.c:126)
==38913==    by 0x10939F: sort_int_vec (main.c:126)
==38913==    by 0x109423: main (main.c:134)
==38913==  Address 0x4a65078 is 24 bytes after a block of size 32 in arena "client"
==38913== 
1
2
3
4
5
==38913== 
==38913== HEAP SUMMARY:
==38913==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38913==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 1,044 bytes allocated
==38913== 
==38913== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==38913== 
==38913== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==38913== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I believe the error is somewhere in my hardcoded implementation of a swap method, but I cannot see where.  While I know the issue is in the `partition_int_vec` function I am including the entire code suite involved for completeness.  If anyone can help me understand and learn why this is giving me such an error I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum
{
    FORWARD,
    REVERSE
} sort_order;

typedef struct
{
    int *array;
    size_t allocated_length;
    size_t active_length;
} Int;

int init_int_vector(Int *vec, size_t length) {
    // Make initial vector allocation
    int *ptr = malloc(length * sizeof(int));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc failed in file %s at line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    vec->allocated_length = length;
    vec->active_length = 0;
    vec->array = ptr;
    return 1;
}

int insert_int_vec(Int *vec, int *elements,
                   size_t num_indices, size_t index) {
    // Ensure that the index is within the active_length
    if (index > vec->active_length) {
        printf("WARNING: The selected index is larger than the active length\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (vec->active_length + num_indices > vec->allocated_length) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannont extend static array allocation in file %s on line %d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return -1;
    }
    // Allocate memory if necessary
    if (vec->active_length + num_indices > vec->allocated_length) {
        size_t size = (vec->active_length + num_indices) * 2;
        int *ptr = (int *)realloc(vec->array, size * sizeof(int));
        // Verify that sufficient memory exists
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failure on file=%s, line=%d", __FILE__, __LINE__);
            free(ptr);
            return -1;
        }
        // allocate memory
        vec->array = ptr;
        vec->allocated_length = size;
    }
    // Add variables and update metadata
    memmove(((char *)vec->array) + (num_indices + index) * sizeof(int),
            ((char *)vec->array) + index * sizeof(int),
            (vec->active_length - index) * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(((char *)vec->array) + index * sizeof(int), elements,
            num_indices * sizeof(int));
    vec->active_length += num_indices;
    return 1;
}

void free_int_vec(Int *vec) {
    free(vec->array);
    vec->array = NULL;
    vec->active_length = 0;
    vec->allocated_length = 0;
}

size_t partition_int_vec(int *arr, int low, int high, sort_order order) {
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    int pivot = arr[low];
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (pivot >= arr[i] && order == FORWARD)
            i++;
        while (pivot < arr[j] && order == FORWARD)
            j--;
        while (pivot <= arr[i] && order == REVERSE)
            i++;
        while (pivot > arr[j] && order == REVERSE)
            j--;
        if (i < j) {
            // Hard coded swap method
            int *a = &arr[i];
            int *b = &arr[j];
            int temp = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = temp;
        }
    }
            // Hard coded swap method
            int *a = &arr[low];
            int *b = &arr[j];
            int temp = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = temp;
    return j;
}

void sort_int_vec(Int *vec, int low, int high, sort_order order) {
    if (low < high)
    {
        size_t pivot = partition_int_vec(vec->array, low, high, order);
        sort_int_vec(vec, low, pivot - 1, order);
        sort_int_vec(vec, pivot + 1, high, order);
    }
}
int main() {
    Int vec;
    init_int_vector(&vec, 5);
    int a[5] = {2, 5, 3, 1, 4};
    insert_int_vec(&vec, a, 5, 0);
    sort_int_vec(&vec, 0, 4, FORWARD);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.active_length; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", vec.array[i]);
    }
    free_int_vec(&vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (pivot >= arr[i] && order == FORWARD)` accesses the array out of bounds. I suspect the other unbounded while loops could too, that's just the first one. https://godbolt.org/z/rzdY9Y98a

Comment: Adding a check to make sure `i` and `j` stay stay in the right range seems to work. https://godbolt.org/z/PcW8Ganhn

Comment: @RetiredNinja if you post the answer I will give you credit for the solution.